# Conditionally accessing Pinia value from template in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I'm trying to render a component only if the value accessed from my `Pinia` store is true -

```
// MessageArea.vue
import { useValidationStore } from '../../stores/ValidationStore.js'

data() {
        return {
            errors: {
                english: useValidationStore().english.error,
            },
        }
    },

<template>
  <p v-if="errors.english">
    <EnglishErrorMessage />
  </p>
</template>
```

By default, it is `false` -

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useValidationStore = defineStore("validation", {
    state: () => {
        return {
            english: {
                input: '',
                error: false,
            },
        }
    }
})
```

I'm also accessing that same value from another file to check for the error -

```
<script>
import { useValidationStore } from '../../../stores/ValidationStore';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            input: useValidationStore().english.message,
            error: useValidationStore().english.error,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        validate(input) {
            this.input = input.target.value
            const legalChars = /^[A-Za-z\s]*$/.test(this.input);
            if (!legalChars && this.input !== "") {
            this.error = true;
        } else if (this.input === "" || (legalChars && !legalChars)) {
            this.error = false;
            }
            console.log(this.error)
            console.log(this.input)
        }
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <input
        @input="validate"
        :value="input"
    />
</template>
```

The console log values are updating reactively. Also, `this.error` will be logged as true when an illegal character is entered into the input. The reactivity is behaving as expected. So, I'm not sure why '' will not render in this case?

Am I not accessing the pinia value correctly in the template?

I've tried to understand what 'mapState()' and 'mapStores()' from the docs and if they can help me but I'm still confused.

Comment: You disable the synchronization with the store by accessing values in `data`, they are unrelated to the store after this point. The docs clearly show how mapState is used, what problem do you have with it? https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#usage-with-the-options-api If you need to sync comp with the store, use mapState and update it with actions. Otherwise you can keep it as is, but it will work exactly as you written, only initial values are picked from the store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mutate the store state in `validate` method.
If you want to use pinia in [`options api`](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#usage-with-the-options-api) you can use `mapState` and `mapWritableState` in computed property to remain rective.
Take a look here [`codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-fast-qzx21b?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) please.